# In modern usage how do Japanese natives regard the differences between 外人, 外国人 and 外人さん?

Tags: word-choice, usage, words, politeness

As a near native speaker of Japanese, I find it annoying to be called 外人 since it seems to imply that I "know nothing about Japan" (outsider). I much prefer 外国人.

**In modern usage**, how do native speakers regard the differences between 外人, 外国人 and 外人さん?

Also are there any newer more "PC" uses of the word coming into use (akin to not calling North American natives 'Indians')?

Comment: Just curious, what is a "near native speaker"?

Comment: on a side note: 外人 from America in Okinawa are called ヤンキー because of the "Y" on their car registration plates. (it's a very pejorative word)

Comment: Yanki has completely different meaning unrelated to foreigners on the mainland honshu, in that it is a person who is very agreesive, or what we would call a punk in america.

Comment: As an addition, 「海外人」 is sometimes used

Comment: One time I brought my skateboard to an 宴会, and one of the teachers said, 「ヤンキーみたい！あれ、お前は本物ヤンキーだよな！」

Comment: @lukman: near native = when ntt calls they dont believe that I am me because I sound J but my name is not! :p

Comment: This may not be an appropriate question for you, as you are not American. But I am curious to know what you think about the sign "aliens" posted in immigration counters at US airports.  For the record, I am not offended, but I feel ill at ease with the desire of shouting out "I am not extra-terrestrial!"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nowadays 外人 and 外国人 are similar in meaning, with the latter seeing less usage. However, traditionally speaking 外人 is a derogatory word that shouldn't be used towards foreigners.  外人 actually doesn't mean foreigner as much as it means "outsider" to a group.  So one could technically refer to people in a different social class/group as you as 外人 and technically be ok.  Though I've have not heard this usage recently.  This usage is the derogatory one btw.Though the only people I've met that know about this distinction have been Japanese teachers and people over 60.

外人さん I have heard is just japanese throwing a title onto the end of a group of people to make it seem more polite like Tanaka-san, though whether or not it is actually more polite is questionable.

lastly, I've actually been called this by my grand-mother-in-law, 異国人(いこくじん) which is a VERY old very polite way of referring to foreigners as it means "people from a different country".  But even my wife was shocked when she heard this, since she has never heard it before.

Comment: It's curious that 外人さん exists when you would never hear something like 中国人さん or 韓国人さん.

Comment: @Derek: It's because Chinese and Korean people are too close by the be considered completely 外人さん

Comment: @Matti: I don't think that's the reason. I've never heard オーストラリア人さん either and it's not because of Japan's close Asiatic bonds to Aussies. @Mark: I like 異国人 because it speaks plainly of the facts, rather than a value judgement filled pejorative term of "outsider".

Comment: @crunchyt but then they'd shorten it to  オージーさん, and that'd sound too similar to おじいさん to an Aussie!

Comment: I'd disagree about the offensiveness. 外人さん is extremely common and used without a sign of offence. You often see girls talking about a "handsome gaijinsan" where it just means "a foreigner" and is if not polite then definitely not offensive. Regarding 外人 - I've heard people using it as a "normal" word even in quite official setting. I've told them later this is not really polite to say this way and they were quite surprised. Which means, again, there's no offence, this is just a normal way to call any foreigner.
When it comes to 外国人 it sounds too politically correct if not in an official talk.

Answer (score 8):

## Answer

I'm a native speaker and I'm sure that there's no difference between them.

It's a evidence for it that Japanese government uses `外人` on its public document.

## Reference

It's said that `外人(さん)` *should not* be used because few people feel discriminated when Japanese call them `外人`.

Thus, especially on public document (e.g. TV programs), `外国人` are used nowadays.

(EDIT) Here are some pages in www.mod.go.jp (Japanese government: Ministry Of Defence) that use the word `外人`.

- http://goo.gl/Y61ghA (A diary of personnel in Western Air Defense Force.)
- http://goo.gl/jNDiki (An introduction of a radio program.)
- http://goo.gl/Qh4tS7 (Photos taken by personnel of 南関東防衛局.)

Japanese government built some cemeteries for foreign people, called `外人墓地`.
An article on Wikipedia mentioned about `外国人` and `外人`.

- http://goo.gl/CPCbL (Wikipedia Japanese: "外国人")

Please take a look at reference #2:

> 「[外人墓地]{がいじんぼち}」や「[外人部隊]{がいじんぶたい}」など[公的]{こうてき}な[名称]{めいしょう}としても[長]{なが}く[使]{つか}われており[差別的]{さべつてき}な[意味合]{いみあ}いはなかったことは[明]{あき}らかである
>
> (Both `外人墓地 (Foreign cemeteries)` and `外人部隊 (Foreign legion)` have been used for long time. So, it's certain that there are no meanings that imply discrimination.)

Comment: Completely agree. I've been called 外人 in the Immigration Bureau by a clerk once by the way and there's completely no offence.

Comment: Can you direct me to some of those government documents? Or even better include it in your answer?

Comment: I've just edited my answer. You can search them yourself: Search on Google -> "site:http://www.mod.go.jp/ 外人 -外国".

Comment: Seems like news sites (NHK, Mainichi etc) uses 外国人 much more often than 外人. For NHK web search, it's [24 for 外人](http://www2.nhk.or.jp/cgisearch/wbs/query.cgi?col=top&ct=&st=&ql=&charset=utf-8&qt=%E5%A4%96%E4%BA%BA) vs [2550 for 外国人](http://www2.nhk.or.jp/cgisearch/wbs/query.cgi?col=site&ct=&ql=1&charset=utf-8&kyoku=&qt=%E5%A4%96%E5%9B%BD%E4%BA%BA). Also, [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaijin#Usage) noted commentators (mostly Western) feel the term to be derogatory. Fascinating.

Answer (score 7):

First, I am not native, but let me share my idea on how I feel.

I also prefer 外国人, but I don't feel offended with 外人.

It could be because they think 外人 is a more common word than 外国人 or everyone around them use 外人, and Japanese use short-form of the words a lot, so may be they don't intend to be discriminate.

I personally feels 外人さん is sarcastic, but may be I am wrong.

Comment: +1 for sarcastic. and "short-form" (for which I forgot the official name like in tokyo daigaku = todai)

Comment: i'm not entirely sure that gaijin is the short form for gaikokujin as they were traditionally two seperate words that have more or less converged in meaning.

Comment: Ditto, I feel like the Japanese person I am speaking to is out of touch if they refer to gaijin-san

Comment: I think 外国人さん was a naive attempt to create a category for foreigners similar to お兄さん、お姉さん etc... I dislike being called 外人 as it feels pejorative and certainly had those connotations long ago.

Comment: I agree. 外人 (4 moras) is easier than 外国人 (6 moras) to pronounce in ordinary conversation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that this isn't mentioned in the above posts. I can't remember the exact sociolinguistic study but the differentiation in usage of both terms for a majority of Japanese speakers sampled was based on race. 外国人 is a catch all term for all foreigners (asian, black, white, etc) and considered the modern polite term. Whereas, 外人 is used for white people and black people.

Comment: Ooh, if you could find a link to this study, that would make this a great answer!

Comment: I'd also be interested in seeing the study. I've never been offended by being called 外人、外人さんor外国人, but I have given a piece of my mind to other foreigners in Japan from Korea or Taiwan who call me a 外人. That's no longer a matter of nationality and purely a matter of skin colour.

Comment: @Elijah <外人 is used for white people and black people.>  Not necessarily.  For example Sumo Mongolian wrestlers are quite often referred to as "外人力士".

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's only one ***modern polite*** word to call a foreigner and it is 外国人. There are other phrases too, such as 海外の人 or 海外の方. The latter one is used more often.

However, you mostly hear 外国人 when a politician talks from a tribune or an overly politically correct Japanese person tries to be polite.

In fact the normal way to refer to a foreigner is 外人 and there's zero offence in it. When talking about a particular person, -さん is added, making 外人さん. Again, this is not offensive even a bit and is hardly ironical. I'd say it is quite polite way to refer to a foreigner even if not suitable for an official setting.

And of course there were always foreigners who feel offended by the 外人 word because apparently the word is made of "outside" and "man" and with some fantasy can be translated as an "alien". Which is well, quite true, so I see no reason to be offended here.

Alien is perfectly normal word to refer to a foreign national or to a foreign introduction.

Comment: I agree that 外人 is not offensive, but I also think that in offensive contexts, 外人 tends to be the word used rather than 外国人. Apart from that, I've always considered 外人 to be a short for 外国人.